# Unable to install Firebase into my Xcode project via cocoapods

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, cocoapods

I am trying to import Firebase into my Xcode file via Cocoapods 1.1.1. My pod file looks something like this.

```html
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'Firebase Login' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for Firebase Login

pod 'Firebase', '~> 3.11'

  target 'Firebase LoginTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    pod 'Firebase'
  end

  target 'Firebase LoginUITests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

end
```

I also tried this.

```html
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'Firebase Login' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for Firebase Login

  target 'Firebase LoginTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    pod 'Firebase'
  end

  target 'Firebase LoginUITests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

end
```

Afterwards, I typed pod install in my terminal and this is what I got.

```html
Analyzing dependencies
[!] Unable to find a specification for `FirebaseAnalytics (= 3.6.0)` depended upon by `Firebase/Core`
```

Is this something I have done wrong or is it a bug with Firebase itself? If it's me, I would appreciate it if someone can help me solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should add those pods before   `target 'Firebase LoginTests' do`
Otherwise you will only include them your test target.

your podfiel should look like this

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'AppName' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for AppName
  pod 'Firebase'
  pod 'Firebase/Auth'
  pod 'Firebase/Database'

  target 'AppName' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

  target 'AppName' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

end
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that is what I did in my first piece of code if you missed that... I also tried adding the Firebase/Auth and Firebase/Database but it's still giving me this "[!] Unable to find a specification for `FirebaseDatabase (= 3.1.1)` depended upon by `Firebase/Database`" Is there any other mistakes you spotted?

Comment: remove your Podfile.lock file and Pods folder and recall pod update the when you fix your podfile

Comment: I don't have a Podfile.lock file because the terminal can't find a specification for my pod for some reason. I also tried updating but apparently 1.1.1 is the most recent Cocoapods available...

Comment: no problem it will be created when you run pod update or pod install one successful time.Can you try with the pod file that i attached with replacing the appname